# Survival probability of a passenger given that the passenger is a female staying in first class.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, conditional-probability

This question is related to the Titanic incident:

> What is the survival probability of a passenger given that the passenger is a female staying in first class?

Information:

- Number of people = 891
- Number of first class people = 216
- Number of second class people = 184
- Number of third class people = 491
- Number of first class female survivors = 91
- Number of first class female died= 3
- Number of first class male survivors = 45
- Number of first class male died= 77
- Number of second class female survivors = 70
- Number of second class female died= 6
- Number of second class male survivors = 17
- Number of second class male died= 91
- Number of third class female survivors = 72
- Number of third class female died= 72
- Number of third class male survivors = 47
- Number of third class male died= 300
- Number of females = 314
- Number of males = 577
- Number of females = 314
- Number of males = 577
- Number of females = 314
- Number of males = 577
- Number of survivors = 342
- Number of dead = 549
- Number of female survivors = 233
- Number of male survivors = 109

The solution is ~ 0.972222

I know that I need to use conditional probability on this question, however, I am not sure what should it look like.

I am not sure if I need to get the P(female), P(first class), P(female|first class), and then P(survivor|(female|first)).

Any clues would be appreciated.

Comment: What data are you given?

Comment: I will edit the post with further data.

Comment: This is still not enough data.  You need to know how the survivors were distributed among the classes and how the sexes were distributed among the classes/survivors.  Your answer is $\frac {33}{36}$ but you can't derive it from the given data.

Comment: @LiborZachoval Ross Millikan is correct. To further demonstrate the point, note that the number of non-first class passengers (according to the data) is $184+491=675$. The number of female passengers ($314$) is less than this, so, without additional information (at the time of writing this comment), it's entirely possible that all female passengers were in second or third class, i.e. there might be no female passengers in first class at all, clearly absurd.

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. I am sorry, I will add on more information. This question comes from a real dataset and so I have to manually extract it, its a combination with programming. I will add in information per each class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's pull out the important information:

Number of first class female survivors = 91

Number of first class female died= 3

So, from this, we can ascertain that there was a total of $91+3=94$ first class female passengers.

Out of the 94 first class female passengers, 91 survived, giving a survival probability of $$\dfrac{91}{94} \approx 0.9680851$$

This is not quite the answer you were given, but this would be the correct answer given the data you provided.

Comment: I agree that is the reason I came to ask here. It is possible that there was a marginal error with the solution. Which market is correct as here. Or is it possible that the result would be different using conditional probabilities? I think the question suggests the use of events. What is the survival probability of a passenger given that the passenger is a female staying in first class? P(survivor|first class woman)? I am sorry I am new to statistics.

Comment: If we were to use conditional probability, then: $P(\text{first class woman}) = \dfrac{94}{891}$, and $P(\text{first class woman survivor}) = \dfrac{91}{891}$, so $P(\text{survivor}|\text{first class woman}) = \dfrac{\tfrac{91}{891}}{\tfrac{94}{891}} = \dfrac{91}{94}$, which is the exact same answer. Perhaps they rounded?  $$\dfrac{91}{891} \approx .102, \dfrac{94}{891} \approx .105, \dfrac{.102}{.105} \approx .971$$ But, the answer you are given still seems very high.

Comment: Yes, that is the right answer actually, I checked it and the proper answer was rounded to 0.968.